# Javascript validation control

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom-events

I wrote a Javascript to validate a few simple fields on my form. My issue is that the code works even when there are no errors on the form.

Specifically it throws an error at `if(openHour > closeHour)`

This is the code:

```
function checkForm()
{  
    var openHour;
    var closeHour;
    var i;

    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
    openHour = document.getElementById("openHours" + i).value;
    closeHour= document.getElementById("closeHours" + i).value;

    if(openHour > closeHour)
    {   
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML= "Opening Error at " + i;  
    return false;
    }
    if(openHour == "0" && closeHour > 0)
    {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML= "Closing Error at " + i;  
    return false;
    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
openHour = parseInt(document.getElementById("openHours" + i).value);
closeHour = parseInt(document.getElementById("closeHours" + i).value);
```

I just needed to parse the values to integers in order to be able to compare them.

Thanks all for your help

Comment: Be careful with `parseInt()` because it can return `NaN` (i.e. if an alpha string is passed to it), which may cause other problems and is often confusing to users if displayed somewhere on screen. [Brendon Cheves's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10097688/1304626) solution is a bit more robust; combining his and yours and checking for `NaN` would be wise.

Answer (score 2):

Are there always default values in the openHours and closeHours fields?

Try setting some defaults, for example:

```
var openHour = 0;
var closeHour = 0;
```

Then check to see if openHours and closedHours have values in them before assigning them:

```
if (document.getElementById("openHours" + i).value != null && document.getElementById("openHours" + i).value != "")
    openHour = document.getElementById("openHours" + i).value;


if (document.getElementById("closeHours" + i).value != null && document.getElementById("closeHours" + i).value != "")
    closeHour = document.getElementById("closeHours" + i).value;
```

Comment: Nop, it still goes in when it shouldn't

Comment: Can you post your HTML? It would be much easier to debug that way. Thanks.

Comment: after adding initial values to the variables it does not cause any issues anymore. Thanks